# string object error while using regex match function

Tags: python, regex

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

search = "bolån"
goog_search = "https://www.google.se/search?source=hp&ei=3_l6WsHAKMiasgHf26zYBQ&q=" + search

r = requests.get(goog_search)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
elements = soup.find_all('cite', {'class': '_WGk'})
f = open('urls.txt','w')

pattern=r'((https?|ftp):\/\/|\b(?:[a-z\d]+\.))(([^\s()<>]+|\((?:[^\s()<>]+|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))?\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\(?:[^\s()<>]+\)))?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:<>]))?'
prog = re.compile(pattern)

for tag in elements:
    result = prog.match(pattern, str(tag))
    print(result)
```

Can't get rid of this error when I am using regex on the string, to get the urls.

This is the error I am getting:

```
for tag in elements:
---> 17     result = prog.match(pattern, str(tag))
     18     print(result)

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't throw such an error, possibly because my google results are different from yours. That said, the `prog` variable isn't defined anywhere, so I'm sure this isn't your real code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey Just posted the updated code. Please check. Please let me know if you have any solution

Comment: Please add the complete error your seeing, including the line it is happening on.

Comment: @AlG- Updated the question with the error

Comment: `prog` is already a regex pattern, you don't have to pass `pattern` to `prog.match`. It should be `result = prog.match(str(tag))`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey- Yes I changed my code according to your suggestion but I am getting `None` as output.

Comment: @Aran-Fey - Any suggestion on why I am getting `None` as output now?

Comment: Because your regex doesn't match the tag. I still can't reproduce your problem, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: @Aran-Fey- The regex matches, its been tested in Regextester, Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) seems you mixed two syntaxes

> The sequence

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
```

> is equivalent to

```
result = re.match(pattern, string)
```

`string` must be passed to `prog.match` not `pattern`, so just

```
prog.match(str(tag))
```

Comment: I am getting `None` as output after the update @Nahuel